# Split and take n words from the end

Tags: python, list, slice

How would you take the last n end words from a split line? For example I have these lines:

```
1. 123.by2.gateway.edge.messenger.live.com
2. messenger.com
3. 10.17.123.45
4. 126.by2.gateway.edge.messenger.live.com
5. 14.messenger.live.com
```

I want to take the 3 last words from the addresses so that for lines 1, 4 & 5 I have 'messenger.live.com' and lines 2 & 3 remain intact. This is what I have done to achieve it, but seems to be lame:

```
link = line.split('.') 
if len(link) > 4: # to bypass the IP address
    plink = link[-1:-3] ?
```

Comment: line #5 after split would have 4 elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to take

```
plink = link[-3:]
```

To ignore the numeric IP you can use this:

```
link = line.split('.')
if len(link) > 3 and link[-1].isalpha():
    plink = link[-3:]
```

This will ignore 2. and 3., while proceeding the 5. correctly (as SilentGhost correctly noted, your code ignores the 5.)

Comment: after I add the line: group.setdefault(plink,dict()).setdefault(host, 0) to the above code, it gives the error message: TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'. Why is that?

Comment: @Adia - you cannot use a list as a dictionary key. Convert it to `tuple(link)` or `'.'.join(link)`-string first.

Comment: After I convert link to tuple, it says: 'AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split''.

Comment: @Adia - sorry, do this with `plink`, not `link`.

Comment: Actually I did that too in this way: plink = tuple(link[-3:]), still giving ''NoneType' object has no attribute 'split''.

Comment: @Adia - if it says something about attribute 'split', then you have a problem with `line`.

Comment: The line worked well until I added the above code. I looks like this: site = line.split(': ')[1].strip('\n'), then 
 link = urlparse(site).hostname.split('.'), the last line of code, is the link line that I have edited, so don't know why after adding the 2nd line (link), it gives that error.

Comment: The problem was the urlparse(site).hostname. Some of the lines didn't have the 'site' string, so it returned None type, that's why. Thanks again for all your helps.